# Ionic 4 Angular AlertController message not showing in release build

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, alert

I've built a small alert service (wrapper for Angular AlertController) in my Ionic 4 project, it works perfectly when I view the project in "ionic serve" (browser), "ionic cordova emulate" (on my connected phone), "ionic cordova build android" (installing the app-debug APK manually on my phone) however when I build the release version of the app using "ionic cordova build android --prod --release" the "message" part of the Alert does not show. The header (title) and the buttons show and work fine still, but the message does not appear.

Here is my method which creates and presents the alert:

```
   /**
 * "Confirm" with callback or "Cancel" alert
 */
async confirmOrCancelAlert(title, message, callback) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: title,
        message: message,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'secondary',
            }, {
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: () => {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    await alert.present();
}
```

This is the code which called the method shown above, which is called from a button click:

```
    /**
 * Answer questions button event click
 */
answerQuestions() {
    if (this.shift.getEarly() && (this.shift.getTimeToStart().asHours() > environment.alertTimes.answerQuestions)) {
        var timeTo = this.durationFormatPipe.transform(this.shift.getStart());
        var message = 'Your shift starts ' + timeTo + ', are you sure you want to answer questions now?';

        this.alertService.confirmOrCancelAlert('You are early!', message, () => {
            this.doAnswerQuestions();
        });
    } else {
        this.doAnswerQuestions();
    }
}
```

Here are two images showing the message messing from the release build but showing in the serve / emulate / debug builds:

[image: Release Build]

[image: Debug Build]

Many thanks in advance for any and all advice.

Comment: How do you call `confirmOrCancelAlert()`? `message` could be empty in the production build.

Comment: @rveerd Thank you for your reply, i've added the peice of code which triggers the `confirmOrCancelAlert()` method, there shouldn't be any difference between the debug or release builds and i'm honestly not sure how I would make it dfferent depending on the build even if I wanted too!

Comment: If you check with your browser dev tools, is the `<div>` with the message present? Also check the CSS styling to see if it is not hidden.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm unsure how to look at the app in browser dev tools for a production build, as using normal emulate or serve the problem does not occur, but when I build with the "--prod --release" flags is when the issue happens. I've tried using "ionic cordova emulate android --prod --release" which I can get to output a release version to my connected phone, however the app does not appear in chrome inspect for me to look at the markup. It would be extremely helpful to debug the production build in dev tools, are you able to do this and do you have any pointers? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a production build in the browser (`ionic serve --prod or `ionic build --prod`)? That would be easier to debug, especially when also generating source maps (AFAIK can be configured in angular.json or `--source-map` option). If not I suggest you try to create a minimal program showing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a timing problem. when you call confirmOrCancelAlert() the timeTo is not prepared yet. so the type of message will be undefined.

try this:

```
    answerQuestions() {
        if (this.shift.getEarly() && (this.shift.getTimeToStart().asHours() > environment.alertTimes.answerQuestions)) {
            var timeTo = this.durationFormatPipe.transform(this.shift.getStart());
            var message = 'Your shift starts ' + timeTo + ', are you sure you want to answer questions now?';

            setTimeout(() => { 
                this.alertService.confirmOrCancelAlert('You are early!', message, () => {
                    this.doAnswerQuestions();
                });
            }, 50);

        } else {
            this.doAnswerQuestions();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I beleive setting a timeout around the functionality would be more of a "patch" than a reliable fix, however your idea did make me think to try changing the "message" variable to just a plain string to test, and the message is still blank in production builds only! Its just baffling me that the issue only occurs when adding the "--prod --release" flags!

Comment: @Matdragon I'm happy that you figured it out

Comment: Unfortuantely the problem persists, it does appear to be an issue with AlertController and ToastController that Ionic have never resolved, so probably going to have to build anew library! If i move the `message` content into the `title` field then it works fine so it is definitly a problem with the Controllers rather than my implementation of it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
async confirmOrCancelAlert(title, myMessage, callback) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: title,
        message: myMessage,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                cssClass: 'secondary',
            }, {
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: () => {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    await alert.present();
}
```

change the name to **myMessage** to make it different than property name. `message: message` will cause a problem I think I had the same problem last year. check it out and inform me of the results.

Comment: @Matdragon did you try this one?